# SignalR websocket failed during handshake

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, websocket, signalr

I'm working on a project in MVC of chat with SignalR.

I have bought a web host with Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS8 and framework 4.5 and websockets enabled (more server details: http://www.register.it/hosting/windows/compare.html, I've got smart pack).

What my test application does is just a test for connect to hub in main page (I have another application, but I want to figure out what is the problem with minimum code possible), and when the client try to connect, this is the error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://otaku2gether.com/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=VHGrwNoDXPMMbtM5dx1e2gF08%2FRWnVkbKUKjGkZkhE4I0p%2FpIFehvooO1shzCxkjU5f308%2FjleQIErTFsZqqe%2B1R4T2GRwMlO0IQbiZE9Z245YZcg6ipRF3cT1TOrqWB&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=10' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing

The view is really simple:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var roomvar = $.connection.chatHub;

            $.connection.hub.logging = true;

            roomvar.client.sendBroadcast = function (message) {
                alert(message);
            };

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>
}
```

and the others prerequisites is done(helped also by the main tutorial https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc ) like startup, and hub.

Does someone have some suggestions?

Comment: try if it works if you use secure websockets (i.e. https / wss)

Comment: Do you mean using https version on my website? It seems the problem remains:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://otaku2gether-com.securesslhosting.it/signalr/connect?transport=webSoc…67Rbq0daeGxyw&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=10' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing